# Batch insert with one-to-many

Tags: hibernate

I have the following situation:

2 tables with relation of one-to-many from parent to child.

The PK of table1 is the FK of the child table (table2) and table2 has another column which combines its PK.

In my code I create instance of the parent entity and add child instances.

when I try to save and commit the new parent instance it says that the child FK cannot be null.

I understand this, but I thought that Hibernate works that it first creates the parent and gives its PK value and then uses it for all child entities.

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you!

Comment: Show the POJOs & other code.